# Executing single function from Shell script in Windows GitBash closes shell unexpectedly

Tags: bash, function, terminal, windows-7, git-bash

I have recently installed [Git For Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) version 2.19.1.windows.1 in my Windows 64Bit (both Windows 7 and 10, in two systems).

Now I have created below script to do some regular tasks easily w/o writing every instruction separately:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Contains functions and methods that can be executed inside Vagrant SSH Session

export SCRIPT_PATH="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd -P)"
export PROJECT_ROOT_PATH="/var/www" PROJECT_ROOT_DIR="/var/www" ROOT_FOLDER="/var/www"

function fcc() {
    echo "########## Frontend Cache clear begins #############"
    [[ "$PWD" =~ "frontend/app" ]] && cd frontend/app
    rm -rf webroot/cache_js && rm -rf webroot/cache_css
    mkdir -m 777 webroot/cache_js && mkdir -m 777 webroot/cache_css
    Console/cake AssetCompress.AssetCompress build -f
    cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -wc && history -cw && exit
    cd /var/www
    echo "########## Frontend Cache clear ends #############"
    keep_shell_open
}

function bocc() {
    ...
}

function bcc() {
    ...
}

function succ() {
    ...
}

function keep_shell_open() { exec $SHELL; };
```

Now when goto script's directory thro' Gitbash terminal & I register the script as below it unexpectedly opens the `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` directory of GitBash:

```
. ./VagrantGuestScript.sh
```

And then when I execute the "fcc" function of this script, it only executes first 2 or 3 lines and then closes the terminal.

Can anyone explain why it opens Gitbash's bin path when trying to register the script & why it closes the terminal after executing only 2/3 lines of the function "fcc" ?

Comment: You call `exit` from the `fcc()` function. What do you `exit` expect to do?

Comment: Yes your point is indeed correct, I've used `exit` before, but somehow I expected it to just exit the command sequence here, sorry my bad. Thanks a lot for pointing that out, it's working now..